# easiest way to put several Python Plotly Express figures on one html file

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

I want to keep the figures in the exact same way, for example, having different data source, subplot title and respective legends near EACH figure.

currently the code is sth. like

```
fig1 = px.line(df_crude_spot_long, x="Date", y="$/bbl", color='type', title='Benchmark Crude Spot Prices', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Bold)
fig1.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="",
    
    title={
        # 'text': "Plot Title",
        # 'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5},
    
    legend_title="Benchmark",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=40,
        color="navy"),
    

    legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01
)
)

fig2 = px.line(df_crude_futures, x="contract month", y='Price', color='futures', title='Latest Crude Oil Futures', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Bold)
fig2.update_layout(
    
    title={
        # 'text': "Plot Title",
        # 'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5},
    
    legend_title="Futures",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=40,
        color="navy"),
    

    legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.8
)
)

fig3
fig4
....
```

As you can see, the data source for different figures are not from the same dataframe.

I tried the 2nd approach in this post, by combining make_subplots and plotly express with code like this

[Is it possible to create a subplot with Plotly Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738987/is-it-possible-to-create-a-subplot-with-plotly-express)

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    subplot_titles=("BenchmarkPrices", "Latest Oil Futures", "Bunker Prices", "Fuel Futures"))

for d in fig1.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'], name = d['name'])), row=1, col=1)

for d in fig2.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'],  name = d['name'])), row=2, col=1)
    

for d in fig3.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'], name = d['name'])), row=2, col=1)

for d in fig4.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=d['x'], y=d['y'],  name = d['name'])), row=2, col=2)
```

but the result has some of the figures not shown properly and all the legends put together on the right side.

[image]

I mentioned Html file in the title because I generally save my figure like below

```
offline.plot({'data':fig},filename='charts.html',auto_open=False)
```

Update 1
The comment section suggested the method in this post
[Plotly saving multiple plots into a single html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868987/plotly-saving-multiple-plots-into-a-single-html/59869358#59869358)

it puts several figures under 1 html but doesn't solve my problem because 1.I need to produce a 2 x 4 charts(2 charts per row and 4 rows in total), with this way it only put 1 chart per row. 2. when I download png from the html, it only shows the 1st figure, even on the html we see the 4

Comment: Do you have a current output diagram so I can see what the assignment looks like? Do you have sample data that can be reproduced?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. For data you can use any data as my question is general: I was just trying to say that they are 4 different dataframes for the 4 charts. I just uploaded the current output, the circled parts are what is not properly shown compared to those individual figure

Comment: In which order do you want to save the 4 figures to HTML file?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869358/16733101?

Comment: thanks Hamzah, I tried with the method of that post but nothing happens, it sorts of work but I need to produce a 2 x 4 charts(2 charts per row and 4 rows in total), with this way it only put 1 chart per row.

Comment: also when I download png from the html, it only shows the 1st figure, even on the html we see the 4

Comment: There is no option to create a legend for each plot, look at this link https://community.plotly.com/t/associating-subplots-legends-with-each-subplot-and-formatting-subplot-titles/33786/2

Comment: Thanks Hamzah, I agree, saw this post maybe a year ago. I still have hope as my question is different, it's about put different figure objects into one html file and one png/jpg photo